# Nav bar submenu container: How to cope with long list-item overflow by wrapping?

Tags: css, overflow, containers, submenu, navbar

I have a hosted blog and I'm modifying templates, however the code for adding submenus to the nav bar is straight out of this great tutorial:

http://www.devinrolsen.com/pure-css-horizontal-menu/

I also read this answer to the question on Stackoverflow http://bit.ly/16KQN0M

But if it's a matter of clearing a float, I can't see where to put `"clear: both;"` in the HTML (at least, nothing I've tried has worked).

And changing `#dropnav li li` to `display: block;` doesn't work either. There must be something I'm missing ...

Here is the CSS. The classes at the top are related to the template but I'll leave them in as they might be relevant.

```
<style type="text/css">
/* Derived from http://www.devinrolsen.com/pure-css-horizontal-menu/ */


#pagebody { position: inherit !important; width: 100%; } 
#pagebody-inner { position: inherit !important; width: 100%; } 

#alpha, #beta, #gamma, #delta {
    display: inline; 
    position: inherit !important; 
    float: left; 
    min-height: 0px; 
}

#dropnav 
{height:31px;} 

#dropnav ul
{margin:0px; padding:0px;}

#dropnav ul li
{display:inline; float:left; list-style:none; position: relative; height:31px; 
width: 175px; } 

#dropnav li a
{color:#efe1ca; font-family:'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; font-weight:400;      
font-size:12px; }


#dropnav li a:hover
{color:#fff; text-decoration: none;}

#dropnav li ul
{margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: none; position: absolute;  z-index: 99; top: 
31px; background-color: #f6f3cb; width: 250px;} 

#dropnav li:hover ul
{display:block; width:250px; } 

#dropnav li li
{list-style:none; display:list-item; font-size:100%;} 

#dropnav li li a
{color: #7a3535; text-decoration:underline; width: 250px; font-size: 16px; } 

#dropnav li li a:hover
{color:#000000; text-decoration:none; } 

li#main {padding: 0px;} /* Sets the padding of items in the main menu */

</style>
```

And HTML markup, with titles removed:

```
<div id="main">
<div id="dropnav">
<ul>

<li class="nav-list-item"><a href="">-------</a>
  <ul id="subnav">
    <li style="width:180px;"><a href="">-------</a></li>
    <li style="width:180px;"><a href="">-------</a></li>
    <li style="width:180px;"><a href="">-------</a></li>
    <li style="width:180px;"><a href="">-------</a></li>
  </ul> 
</li>

<li class="nav-list-item"><a href="">-------</a>
  <ul id="subnav">
    <li style="width:180px;"><a href="">-------</a></li>
    <li style="width:180px;"><a href="">-------</li>
  </ul> 
</li>

</ul> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  http://jsfiddle.net/EpmSy/

Comment: Do you want the text to wrap, or not to wrap?

Comment: Yes it's wrapping but the container size is not increasing with it. I want the container to adjust too.

Comment: If there is another `li` below it, the text from the long one is overwriting the next ... and if it's last on the list, the container ends and the text hangs out the bottom over the page content.

Comment: It seems to be behaving as if the line height has been fixed. Could it be inheriting the line height from the nav bar? I've tried `height: auto;` though.

Comment: Oh, hey! It's fixed - I didn't try `height: auto` in the `dropnav li li` because someone said to put all styles onto the `a` or `a:hover`- however, it works so I'm done :-)